# Identifying Auto Scaled Azure Instances?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

With a Small instance worker role containing a WCF service, I want it to auto-scale if the memory usage goes to *n*%. The WCF application uses Azure SQL Database, which is a Singleton in my application. If/when the application tier autoscales, what is "different" between the two systems that can be tracked by the database? Is there a way to alter the "Application Name" in a DB connection string when things scale-up? Is there an Azure-specific ID that can be trapped and logged in the DB? I could fall-back on hacking the connection string and passing that into SQL myself, but I am hoping there is something built-in I can use now.

I tried looking around on the Azure team's site(s) but have seen nothing clear/definitive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections to SQL Azure are tracked by the host name which is different from machine to machine. Is this what you're trying to achieve by passing machine name into connection string?

You can monitor the connections to SQL Azure database by executing the following query:

```
SELECT
      e.connection_id,
      s.session_id,
      s.login_name,
      s.last_request_end_time,
      s.cpu_time,
      s.host_name
FROM
      sys.dm_exec_sessions s
      INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections e
      ON s.session_id = e.session_id
```

I want to also mention that Azure's native auto-scaling feature does not support auto-scaling based on memory utilization and only based on CPU utilization. To auto-scale based on anything but CPU or queue counts, you'll need to use WASABi API or AzureWatch

Comment: That looks good, but now that I see how it works, it appears to be "expensive" to calculate/call in every sproc I have that writes data. I may have to calculate it in the worker role after all. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to have a single Small cloud worker role going to a database to service high-volume requests. If CPU threshold is reached, I want another instance to spin-up. Both instances need to go to the same DB. For troubleshooting purposes, I want the DB to capture an instance-id so I can review performance of say instance0 vs instance1 during/after the spin-up period.

Comment: You can capture and analyze performance counters as they come from each of the servers to get a view of performance of one instance vs. the other.  Furthermore, you can publish a custom performance counter with performance characteristics that you want to monitor (ie: how long it took for controller's actions to get generated) and then capture that perf counter with help of Azure diagnostics